# Javascript - Splitting an array to uneven sections

Tags: javascript

I have an array like [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] and a given number like 6, and I want the result to be like this:

```
[1,2]
[3,4]
[5,6]
[7]
[8]
[9]
```

Or if I had number 3:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Or for 4:

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5]
[6,7]
[8,9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
function splitArray(input, splitNumber){
  const arrayLenght = input.length;
  if(arrayLenght < splitNumber)
    return; //it's not doable :/
  
  const minMembers = Math.floor(arrayLenght / splitNumber);
  let remainNumber = arrayLenght - (minMembers*splitNumber);
  
  let i = 0;
  for(let j=0; j<splitNumber; j++){
    
    let myArray = [];
    
    for(let i=0; i < minMembers; i++)
        myArray.push(input.shift());
    
    if(remainNumber > 0){
        myArray.push(input.shift());
      remainNumber--;
    }
    
    console.log(myArray);
  }
}
```

and calling it:

```
splitArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 6);
```

the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Mostafam70/dtr9hzpu/42/